# How can I center an image and text in a short paragraph?

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
<p style="height: 25px; line-height: 25px;">
   <img width="16" height="16" src="/Content/images/icons/fugue/book-open.png" style="margin-top: 3px;">Test - 5</p>
```

I have tried some things with line-height but it does not seem to work. Always the text is going to be just a few words.

How can I make the center of the image line up with the center of the text?

So what I would like is as below where the xs represent the image:

```
xxx
xxx text
xxx
```

Comment: Sorry. I will have the image to the left of the text. I would like the center line of the image to line up with the center of the text horizontally.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752678/how-to-stop-elements-moving-around/10752985#10752985

Answer (score 2):

you havn't said if you want to line up the elements horizontally or vertically, so i'm going to explain both:

**for vertical alignment:**
since images are inline-blocks by default, they can easily be positioned using [`text-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-align). just add a like-break (`<br/>`) between them or add a `display: block`.styling to the image and use `text-align: center` on your paragraph.

[see it working on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XPWWb/1/).

**for horizontal alignment:**
the easiest solution is to use [`position: relative`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position) and `top:2px` to move the icon down.

[see it working on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XPWWb/2/)

Comment: Or a display: block; on the img instead of the <br /> might be a better option.

Comment: @oezi - I added a bit more explanation to the question

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/vertical-align) on the image element?

Answer (score 0):

If you set a `vertical-align: middle;` on the `img` that should do it!

Note: I've removed the width and height attributes from the example, but see here: http://jsfiddle.net/SZYtB/